# Get @@RowCount and @@ErrorFlag from an SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the code below:

```
declare @errorflag int
declare @rowcount int

DELETE FROM OrderItem WHERE OrderID=1
SET @errorflag = @errorflag + @@Error --line 4
set @rowcount = @@RowCount
```

However, rowcount is set to 1 in the above (because line 4 sets it to 1 (rather than line 3)).  How do I get the rowcount and errorflag from the previous SQL statement?

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: You can write a select statement or print statement at the last of the query..

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @errorflag = @errorflag + @@Error
    , @rowcount = @@RowCount
```